Undefined method `name' for an instance of Array (NoMethodError)
I am trying to add an element into an instance of array by using push(<<) to insert variables new_name and new_origin into ingredients array but I am receiving this error: undefined method `name' for an instance of Array (NoMethodError)
There are two class instances - Menu and Ingredient
class Menu
    attr_accessor : dessert, :ingredients

    def initialize (dessert, ingredients)
           @dessert = dessert
           @ingredients = ingredients
    end
end

class Ingredient
    attr_accessor :name, :origin

    def initialize (name, origin)
           @name = name
           @origin = origin
    end
end

After a text file that contains Menu and ingredient information, I want to add a new ingredient information to the existing information.
Created arrays - menu and ingredient
menu = Menu.new(dessert, ingredients)
ingredient = Ingredient.new(name, origin)

Where error occurs
This below code: update the existing menu information
read_string is a function that display the prompt and return the read string.
#menus contains the read menu file information
def menu_update(menus)
  menu_id = read_integer_in_range("Enter the Menu to edit: ", 1, menus.length)
  menu_id = menu_id - 1
  ingredient_count = menus[menu_id].ingredients.length
  new_name = read_string("Enter a name for new ingredient: ")
  new_origin = read_string("Enter a origin for new ingredient: ")
  menus[menu_id].ingredients.name << new_name
  menus[menu_id].ingredients.origin << new_origin

  puts("Update info"
  puts("Name: #{menus[menu_id].ingredients[ingredient_count].name}")
  puts("Name: #{menus[menu_id].ingredients[ingredient_count].origin}")
end

Expected output:
Update info
Name: peanut
Location: USA


Your code contains some typos like extra spaces and missing parentheses.  It's best to post code without syntax errors. Also, try to post code that we can easily run ourselves, e.g. replacing custom methods like read_string with a simple gets call makes it much easier for us to replicate your problem. See [mre].

You didn't show how you set the variable ingredients when doing menu = Menu.new(dessert, ingredients).


I am receiving this error: undefined method `name' for an instance of Array (NoMethodError)

menus[menu_id].ingredients is an array. Arrays don't respond to name:
[].name
# undefined method `name' for an instance of Array (NoMethodError)

Likewise, calling menus[menu_id].ingredients.name will raise a NoMethodError:
menus[menu_id].ingredients.name << new_name
#                         ^^^^^
#                         won't work

menus[menu_id].ingredients.origin << new_origin
#                         ^^^^^^^
#                         won't work either


I am trying to add an element into an instance of array by using push(<<) to insert variables new_name and new_origin into ingredients array

The element you want to push to the array is another Ingredient instance with new_name and new_origins holding the values for the ingredient's name and origin attributes.
To do this, you have to create a new Ingredient instance, set its name and origin attributes, and then add that newly created instance to the menu's ingredients array via <<:
new_ingredient = Ingredient.new(new_name, new_origin)
menus[menu_id].ingredients << new_ingredient

alternatively:
menus[menu_id].ingredients << Ingredient.new(new_name, new_origin)

If you have assigned the new ingredient to a variable, you can print it via:
puts("Update info")
puts("Name: #{new_ingredient.name}")
puts("Origin: #{new_ingredient.origin}")

Alternatively, you could refer to the last item in the menu's ingredients array via [-1]: (see accessing elements)
puts("Update info")
puts("Name: #{menus[menu_id].ingredients[-1].name}")
puts("Origin: #{menus[menu_id].ingredients[-1].origin}")

Within your method, new_ingredient and menus[menu_id].ingredients[-1] will be the very same object if you incorporate the suggested changes.
